# Looping through list of coordinates to create polygons on Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, google-earth-engine

I have imported a CSV file with just one column. Each row of the column has multiple coordinates required to draw a polygon. (This was collected on the ground)

I have used the below code to extract the coordinates from the CSV as a list

```
var poly = table2.aggregate_array('wkt')  //wkt being the column name
```

Now essentially, I would want to loop through the list, create and display the polygons on the map.

I am looking for something like this:

```
var newPolygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(poly[i])
```

If there is a simpler way to use the coordinates to plot polygons can you let me know?

Comment: I found a way around this problem by ingesting the CSV file with polygon coordinates into QGIS and converting it to a polygon shapefile. Now I am able to use this table in Google Earth Engine directly to create map layers and conduct other operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information on the CRS of your coordinates, and their construction., it will be difficult to create a working solution, but I'll make assumptions along the way and see if you can adapt it to your solution.  What you'll want to do is map a function to your list that will take each element of the list (the polygon coordinates) and make a geometry with it.  Something like this.

```
var makeFeatureFromGeometry = function(coords){
         var newGeometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords, CRS); // you will have to supply the CRS of the coordinates
         return ee.Feature(newGeometry);
}
var myFeatureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(poly.map(makeFeatureFromGeometry));

Map.addLayer(myFeatureCollection);
```

Try this and if you receive error messages, I'll see if I can help you create a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sean! This was exactly the gap in my understanding. However, I am now facing an error with coords, as it is of type string and I am unable to convert it to list despite trying out a lot of functions.

The error I am getting while constructing the polygon is: "GeometryConstructors.Polygon, argument 'coordinates': Invalid type. Expected: List<Object>. Actual: String."

Comment: My coordinates are of the format: [[76.47441303,11.91755698],[76.47439336,11.91753608],[76.47435523,11.91751293],[76.47429992,11.91750973],[76.47426618,11.91756832],[76.47436792,11.91753208],[76.47452594,11.91749775],[76.47441303,11.91755698]] 
This is accepted while directly using it in     ee.Geometry.polygon
But not while mapping it is as variable coors

Comment: Hi Abheeshta,  do the following: print(poly) and look in the console what appears.  It might be a text string,  which is why you can't read it with the function I wrote.  It is expecting a list...

Comment: Yes, it is a text string. When I try to parse it to a list using  JSON.parse it throws an error saying "element e is not found at position 0"

Comment: Look in the docs of the code editor, under ee.String.  perhaps if you cast it to an ee.String() you will then be able to use the functions there to parse it.  I've never used wkt with Earth Engine, so I'm afraid I'm not much help.

Comment: I have tried to upload a wkt as a csv, and the value I get in the feature collection is a string that looks like this.     POLYGON ((76.47441303 11.91755698, 76.47439336 11.91753608, 76.47435523 11.91751293, 76.47429992 11.91750973, 76.47426618 11.91756832, 76.47436792 11.91753208, 76.47452594 11.91749775, 76.4744130311.91755698)).  Could you post your full code (and share your asset?)